# What are the options to fix/work-around a bazel package conflict?

Tags: bazel

I'm seeing the following error:

```
link: package conflict error: google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations: multiple copies of package passed to linker:
    @go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto
    @org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations:annotations
Set "importmap" to different paths or use 'bazel cquery' to ensure only one
package with this path is linked.
```

`@org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations:annotations` is being brought in through:

```
@com_github_uber_cadence//service/history:go_default_library
@com_github_uber_cadence//service/history:history
@com_github_uber_cadence//common/resource:resource
@com_github_uber_cadence//common/archiver/provider:provider
@com_github_uber_cadence//common/archiver/gcloud:gcloud
@com_github_uber_cadence//common/archiver/gcloud/connector:connector
@com_google_cloud_go_storage//:storage
@org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/iam/v1:iam
@org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations:annotations
```

Can `@org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations:annotations` be disabled or shadowed by `@go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto`? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option I went with:

Change what uses `@org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations` to use `@go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto` instead by using appropriate `gazelle:resolve` directives in the `repositories.bzl` file:

```
    go_repository(
        name = "com_google_cloud_go",
        build_directives = [
            # @go_googleapis is the modern version of @org_golang_google_genproto
            # use @go_googleapis to avoid dependency conflicts between the two
            "gazelle:resolve go google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/iam/v1 @go_googleapis//google/iam/v1:iam_go_proto",  # keep
        ],
        …
    )

    go_repository(
        name = "com_google_cloud_go_storage",
        build_directives = [
            # @go_googleapis is the modern version of @org_golang_google_genproto
            # use @go_googleapis to avoid dependency conflicts between the two
            "gazelle:resolve go google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/iam/v1 @go_googleapis//google/iam/v1:iam_go_proto",  # keep
            "gazelle:resolve go google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/type/expr @go_googleapis//google/type:expr_go_proto",  # keep
            "gazelle:resolve go google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations @go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto",  # keep
        ],
        …
    )
```

The following also works but I preferred the above since it uses the newer library:

Change what uses `@go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto` to use `@org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations` instead by using appropriate `gazelle:resolve` directives in the root `BUILD` file:

```
# gazelle:resolve go google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations @org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations
```

Other options considered and reasons I didn't go with them:

1. Upgrade to the latest `@com_google_cloud_go_storage`. Didn't go with this option because the latest version (`v1.24.0` at the time of this post) still uses `@org_golang_google_genproto`.
2. Upgrade `@com_google_cloud_go_storage` to use `@go_googleapis`. Didn't go with this option because it looked too difficult to get merged.
3. `repo_mapping = {"@org_golang_google_genproto" : "@go_googleapis"}` for `com_google_cloud_go_storage`. Didn't go with this option because `@go_googleapis` isn't a drop-in replacement for `@org_golang_google_genproto` (`@go_googleapis` uses the prefix `google` while `@org_golang_google_genproto` uses the prefix `googleapis`).
4. `"gazelle:exclude **/common/archiver/gcloud/**"` for `com_github_uber_cadence`. Didn't go with this option because `common/archiver/provider` depends on `common/archiver/gcloud`.
5. Set prefix for `go_googleapis` from `google` to `googleapis`. Didn't go with this option because it breaks expectations for those familiar with `go_googleapis` standard practice.